# O tipo de entidade requer que uma chave primária seja definida

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Estou criando uma web api utilizando o **.net 5**

O objetivo da aplicação é fazer um cadastro simples de usuário, e futuramente outros tipos de cadastro

Estou utilizando uma arquitetura **DDD**, e na minha camada de repositório eu uso o **Entity Framework Core Versão 5.0.8** com uma conexão a um banco **SQL Server**

Essa é a minha classe de Contexto com o banco **ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoa { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Licenca> Licenca { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaConfig>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<LicencaConfig>();


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Eu tenho uma classe de configuração de cada entidade, vou usar de exemplo a classe **Pessoa** que é onde eu estou fazendo os primeiros testes da minha aplicação

Classe de configuração da Pessoa

```
public class PessoaConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Pessoa> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Cliente");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.CodigoCliente);

        builder.Property(x => x.CodigoCliente).HasColumnName("cd_cliente");
        builder.Property(x => x.TipoPessoa).HasColumnName("tp_pessoa");
        builder.Property(x => x.Advogado).HasColumnName("fl_advogado");
        builder.Property(x => x.Captador).HasColumnName("fl_captador");
        builder.Property(x => x.Cobrador).HasColumnName("fl_cobrador");
        builder.Property(x => x.Cliente).HasColumnName("fl_cliente");
        builder.Property(x => x.Fornecedor).HasColumnName("fl_fornecedor");
        builder.Property(x => x.Devedor).HasColumnName("fl_devedor");
        builder.Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnName("no_cliente");
    }
}
```

O meu problema é o sequinte, na minha classe de Repositorio, quando eu vou criar a pessoa no meu banco ele estoura um erro.

Meu Metodo no Repositorio

```
public class PessoaRepository : IPessoaRepository
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IErrorMenssageService _svcError;

    public PessoaRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, IErrorMenssageService svcError)
    {
        _context = context;
        _svcError = svcError;
    }

    public void Criar(Pessoa obj)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Pessoa.Add(obj); //Meu erro estoura nessa linha
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _svcError.InserirMensagem(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Nome do Erro

`The entity type 'Pessoa' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.`

Ja fiz varais pesquisas para tentar resolver, e todas elas falam pra mim ter na classe de configuração esse trecho de codigo (que esta no codigo acima)

`builder.HasKey(x => x.CodigoCliente);`

Mas isso nao resolve meu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você precisa instanciar sua classe de configuração da seguinte forma:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PessoaConfig());
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LicencaConfig());


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda !!!